# Return array of generic type, depending on array of generic parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, function, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to achieve something that I don't really know if it's possible currently in TypeScript.

The main goal is create a function that, depending on its parameter (an array), will return an array of different typed function, each function returned depending on each member of the array. And, on top of that, the functions types are dependent on some generics.

Here I have a non-working but more or less close code:

```js
type FirstThing<T> = () => T;
type SecondThing<T,X> = (something: X) => T;

type AllThings<T,X> = FirstThing<T> | SecondThing<T,X>;

type FunctionTypes = "firstThing" | " secondThing";

type FunctionParams = {
    option1: FunctionTypes,
    option2: boolean,
}

function someFunction<T, X>(p: FunctionParams[]): AllThings<T,X>[] {
    return p.map(fp => {
        const auxFn = (fp.option1 == "firstThing" ? () => {
            return "aa" as T;
        } : (smth: X) => {
            return "bb" as T
        });
        if (fp.option1 == "firstThing") {
            return auxFn as FirstThing<T>;
        } else {
            return auxFn as SecondThing<T,X>;
        }    
    });
}
```

As you can see, this is not really working, because the typing is resolved when I call the function, and is not dependent on the `FunctionParams` array, which is not genericly typed.

My main goal, is, if for example, I got to call the function like this:

```js
const [f1,f2] = someFunction<string, number>([{option1: "firstThing"}, {option1: "secondThing"}]);
```

Then the `f1` and `f2`, would be correctly typed `FirstThing<T>` and `SecondThing<T,X>` bu with the possibility that the `T` of `f1` and the `T` of `f2` can be of different type (with my current code, all of the functions will be with the same generics).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense that `f1` would have type `FirstThing<T>` when `T` is not defined.  I think maybe you want `f1` and `f2` to be generic functions, but I'm not sure which type parameters should be unbound and which should be bound.  What's the point of `string` and `number` in your hypothetical call to `someFunction`?  Could you possibly write the exact type you expect `f1` and `f2` to be?  If they are generic, write out the type like `declare function f1<T>(): T` or `declare function f2<T>(x: number): T` or whatever you're really looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs another generic parameter to keep track of the given function params:

```
function someFunction<T, X, P extends FunctionParams[]>(
    p: [...P]
): {
    [K in keyof P]: P[K]["option1"] extends "firstThing"
        ? FirstThing<T>
        : SecondThing<T, X>;
} {
```

However, you'll notice that an error is emitted when you try to use it:

```
const [f1, f2] = someFunction<string, number>([
    { option1: "firstThing" },
    { option1: "secondThing" },
]);
```

This is because if you pass one (or two) type parameters, *you have to pass all of them*. That would defeat the point of strongly typing this function, because we'd have to repeat ourselves. Without partial type inference support  (see [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)), we have to curry the function:

```
function someFunction<T, X>() {
    return function curried<P extends FunctionParams[]>(
        p: [...P]
    ): {
        [K in keyof P]: P[K]["option1"] extends "firstThing"
            ? FirstThing<T>
            : SecondThing<T, X>;
    } {
```

(*Subtly casting the return type to get rid of the error there*)

```
}) as ReturnType<typeof curried<P>>;
```

and now it works!

```
const [f1, f2] = someFunction<string, number>()([
    { option1: "firstThing" },
    { option1: "secondThing" },
]);
```

`f1`'s type is `FirstThing<string>`, and `f2`'s type is `SecondThing<string, number>`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7ACoAs4DsDmAeVAPigF4oAKASlONQG4AoUSKAZQgGMB7LAEw2z5UAGigANYmXJIuAWwjBMuAFzjqJWoybhoAQQA2+gbiQFRE0rEQpjQ4gB82nHvyVDzhLc2gwArlg5gOB5UHSRLACIAM2s0NwioRwikZz5bCK8dWH9A4KwABQBDBELZcLIAbwYoGqguMCCeAEZVPwDGrFDIJEYAXy0onI6oGXk23J4zcUIqKCraqAQFXwQsKEH2vKgOFYQ4CF48fKgIAA9gCD5w8Y6ikrKAbQBdGeqF2rBVB4A6X-ynt41SiqebvGoPADSUGwUAA1hAQFwolB-qp8pCng8IvUOk0Ik8TudLrxwtFYulAWDagB+KzIOKCAiESlUqCqdjcNJuKYSRgLXpzFm1JbAFZrMDfWSFMDkchRMDqYig1k1TkoKCFXynGBrEhClXrCU4vJNUhkMn0ikGg202YaQXWx3C5arKARQqFBKFcL0fVOmq9P2O1TSWSKVRiRUO-3WkVit0AIwTXp9fJjYP6DCDtTgyLlRoaJrN5pilvi1GVTrjrs12rW3rpNm5RDTBoFEH0KWj-ur9a1Oo14Q5LlsPM82YDft61AbACUXZ0dHhvEjtrt9od8oRx-y+lm1cAoA8ok1RFEAEwEsijCA3PJ4FB7XCiLC+WQJiAIGaUcgPSkVOpC2aVQLSbQQEl6YR-0A3EQJSTlXHAqBIIYJ5KEYIA)